# Not attaching MvvmCross Unified API to debug in XS

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, xamarin, mvvmcross

Not sure if it is a MvvmCross problem or Xamarin, but the problem is:

I want to debug my Mvvm iOS Unified API app. But it is having a weird behavior.
When it is debugging in Xamarin Studio, attached, so I can breakpoint, my app crashes and in the Application Output I got:

```
    2015-01-13 17:06:48.998 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical: Stacktrace:

    2015-01-13 17:06:48.999 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical: 
    Native stacktrace:

    2015-01-13 17:06:49.106 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical:   0   Chat.Mobile.Touch                   0x000000010105bcd4 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 268
    2015-01-13 17:06:49.106 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical:   1   Chat.Mobile.Touch                   0x0000000101065afc mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 316
    2015-01-13 17:06:49.107 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001940d095c _sigtramp + 68
    2015-01-13 17:06:49.107 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical:   3   Chat.Mobile.Touch                   0x000000010104ca7c add_var + 472
    2015-01-13 17:06:49.107 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical:   4   Chat.Mobile.Touch                   0x000000010104ca7c add_var + 472
    2015-01-13 17:06:49.107 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical:   5   Chat.Mobile.Touch                   0x000000010104c178 frame_commands + 712
    2015-01-13 17:06:49.108 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical:   6   Chat.Mobile.Touch                   0x0000000101045fdc debugger_thread + 1744
    2015-01-13 17:06:49.108 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical:   7   Chat.Mobile.Touch                   0x000000010111346c inner_start_thread + 192
    2015-01-13 17:06:49.108 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical:   8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001940d7e80 <redacted> + 164
    2015-01-13 17:06:49.108 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical:   9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001940d7ddc <redacted> + 0
    2015-01-13 17:06:49.108 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical:   10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001940d4fb0 thread_start + 4
    2015-01-13 17:06:49.108 Chat.Mobile.Touch[4375:1489072] critical: 
    =================================================================
    Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
    used by your application.
    =================================================================
```

While, when running not attached to XS, the app runs perfectly. Any idea what the problem is?

The code crashes when calling Authorize..

```
    try
    {
            Authorize (value); // I have a breakpoint here working... But it crashes during the call..
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            _exceptionService.TreatException (e);
    }

    private void Authorize(object parameter)
    {
            var redirectUrl = parameter as string; //I have another breakpoint here, not breaking. Crashing before it.
            (...)

            ChangePresentation(new MvxRootPresentationHint(typeof (ThreadsListViewModel)));
    }
```

Thanks in regards.

Comment: Sounds like one for Xamarin support? (It is what you pay them for...)

Comment: yeah, weird. already posted at forum. waitin for them answer.